# Center button and form

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

I've been playing around with an input field and a submit button, but can't get them centered on mobile. Also, it'd be good if they have the same width, but somehow the input field is always wider. Any ideas?

[Image of mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39uMs.png)

```css
input {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
  
@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    button {
  max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  input {
          max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<form action="https://URL.co.uk" method="get" target="_blank"><input name="utm_source" type="hidden" value="[partner-handle]" /> <input name="utm_medium" type="hidden" value="affiliate" /><input name="utm_campaign" type="hidden" value="[partner-campaign]" /> <input style="color: #252e5d; font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;" maxlength="8" name="vrm" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Reg" /> <button style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px;">Compare prices</button></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mobile, just add:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

```css
<style>
input {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
  
@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    button {
  max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  }
  
  input {
          max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto 8px;
  display: block;
}
  
  </style>
```

```html
<form action="https://URL.co.uk" method="get" target="_blank"><input name="utm_source" type="hidden" value="[partner-handle]" /> <input name="utm_medium" type="hidden" value="affiliate" /><input name="utm_campaign" type="hidden" value="[partner-campaign]" /> <input style="color: #252e5d; font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;" maxlength="8" name="vrm" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Reg" /> <button style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px;">Compare prices</button></form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below CSS in media query:

```css
@media (max-width:767px){
    button{
      display:table;
      margin:0 auto;
    }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  margin-left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  button {
    max-width: none;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
    background-color: #1b55f5;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  input {
    max-width: none;
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 0px solid #252e5d;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  @media (max-width:767px) {
    button, input{
      display: table;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
```

```html
<form action="https://URL.co.uk" method="get" target="_blank"><input name="utm_source" type="hidden" value="[partner-handle]" /> <input name="utm_medium" type="hidden" value="affiliate" /><input name="utm_campaign" type="hidden" value="[partner-campaign]" /> <input style="color: #252e5d; font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;"
    maxlength="8" name="vrm" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Reg" /> <button style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px;">Compare prices</button></form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is happening because of the  `margin-left:10px` on the button.

```css
<style>
input {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 192px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 
  
@media screen and (max-width: 440px) {
    button {
  max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #1b55f5;
  background-color: #1b55f5;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  input {
          max-width: none;
  width: 80%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 0px solid #252e5d;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
  
  </style>
```

```html
<form action="https://URL.co.uk" method="get" target="_blank"><input name="utm_source" type="hidden" value="[partner-handle]" /> <input name="utm_medium" type="hidden" value="affiliate" /><input name="utm_campaign" type="hidden" value="[partner-campaign]" /> <input style="color: #252e5d; font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;" maxlength="8" name="vrm" type="text" value="" placeholder="Enter your Reg" /> <button style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 18px;">Compare prices</button></form>
```